# javascript search array, return found keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to search for a value in an array and return the found keys with values.

Example:

```
var arr=['Volvo460', 'Fiat500', 'fiat400', 'volvo C7', 'Saab 95'];
var search = 'volvo';
```

expected result:

```
returned_array = ['Volvo460','volvo C7'];
```

Anyone?

**Edit** - conformed array ;-)

Comment: not a valid array format in JS

Comment: `1=>` ?? what is this?

Comment: doesn't this simply boil down to a linear search, else use JS objects.

Comment: Perhaps it is more easy to return the id's ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this answers:

```
var arr=['Volvo460', 'Fiat500', 'fiat400', 'volvo C7', 'Saab 95'];
var search = 'volvo';

var returned_array =arr.filter(function(itm,i,a){
  if(itm.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1)
    return i==a.indexOf(itm);
});

alert(returned_array);
```

Here is an working [example](http://jsbin.com/rurixoyeve/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** for filtering values from an array

```js
var arr = [
  'Volvo460',
  'Fiat500',
  'fiat400',
  'volvo C7',
  'Saab 95'
];
var search = 'volvo';

var res = arr.filter(function(v) {
  // convert both string to lower to make it case insensitive
  return v.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>')
```

Comment: Don't you have you're parameters mixed up in your `forEach` call?

Comment: What if it just is an as described? (eg. not objectified..)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [
   'Volvo460',
   'Fiat500',
   'fiat400',
   'volvo C7',
   'Saab 95'
];
var search = 'volvo',

arr.map(function(v) {
  if(v.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1) return v;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems though that the returned array is filled with empty "spaces"
alert(result) -> customer_id,customer_name,customer_finance_id,,,,
Notice the four commas..

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var obj = {
  1: 'Volvo460',
  2: 'Fiat500',
  3: 'Fiat400',
  4: 'volvo C7',
  5: 'Saab 95'
};
var search = 'volvo'
for (key in obj) {  
    if (obj[key].toLowerCase().search(search) == 0)
        console.log('found:' + key + '=' + obj[key])
}
```

the keys can be strings also:

```
var obj = {
  'a': 'Volvo460',
  'b': 'Fiat500',
  'c': 'Fiat400',
  'd': 'volvo C7',
  'e': 'Saab 95'
};
var search = 'volvo'
for (key in obj) {  
    if (obj[key].toLowerCase().search(search) == 0)
        console.log('found:' + key + '=' + obj[key])
}
```

if you need to add one key at a time you can do like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj['a'] = 'Volvo460';
obj['b'] = 'Fiat500',
obj['c'] = 'Fiat400',
obj['d'] = 'volvo C7',
obj['e'] = 'Saab 95'

var search = 'volvo'
for (key in obj){   
    if (obj[key].toLowerCase().search(search) == 0)
        console.log('found:' + key + '=' + obj[key])
}
```

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lfpk6zgo/5/

Answer (score 1):

A proposal with a regular expression

```js
var arr = ['Volvo460', 'Fiat500', 'fiat400', 'volvo C7', 'Saab 95'];
    search = RegExp('volvo', 'i'),
    result = arr.filter(search.test.bind(search));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = ["volvoCar", "123volvo", "BMW", "VW", "etc"],
new_array = [];

for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i].match(/volvo/ig)){
      new_array.push(arr[i]);
   }

}
console.log(new_array);
```